# explain this output regarding division by zero

Tags: java

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        int a=10;
        int b=0;
        System.out.println(a/b); // runtime error

        double c=10;
        double d=0;
        System.out.println(c/d);        
    }        
}
```

runtime error occur when run this code from the line which i marked and that is due to divide by zero and other one works fine and its also has a divide by zero expression.
what is the reason for these two different behaviors ?